# How to create a javascript library to be used on angular app and on the server with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'd like to create a js library that can be used in both the browser using angular and on the server using node.js.

I'm a bit confused on how to set this up. I'd like to use typescript as well. But I'm so used to something like angular-cli which takes care of all the setup (webpack, ts, babel, etc) that I'm a bit lost on how to start a javascript project using those tool and I assume I'll have to setup all the configuration by hand.

Is there anything I'd have to look out for when trying to support the library for both browser and server? I guess I should be targeting es5. I know in the tsconfig I can specify the target as es5, what about the module and module resolution in the tsconfig? Anything else to do in the babel config and webpack?

Any one has good tutorials? links? starter?

Comment: Export the required modules from the file. Create an NPM package. Will work for both angular app and node backend

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not so familiar with node.js

Answer (score 0):

there is actually a built in command in Angular CLI to create a library:
"ng generate library *yourLibrary*--prefix *demoPrefix*"

now a new projects directory is created with your folder inside + the relevant config json.

you'll need to create a public API next to allow access to this library -> edit the public api.ts file of your newly created lib to do this and provide -> export the relevant services, modules and models.

you can also add components to your library using CLI like so:

ng generate component poster --project=*demoLibrary*

here's an article that might help
https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5

Comment: Thanks, I'm well aware of this but would this be able to run on node.js ?

Comment: if you have an API then why not?

Comment: I guess I'll have to be careful not to use angular stuff like httpclient

Answer (score 0):

Write the library in plain javascript (or typescript) using no dependencies

Comment: what if i need to make some http request and I want to write in es6 style

Comment: You can use webpack so you write nodejs code then use it in the browser (angularjs or not )